# getting error "Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

First of all..sorry for my bad english.

I installed a fresh copy of laravel 5 on my localhost and configured its **database.php** and **.env** file. it was running well.

After that i added (as stated here https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)

```
    "require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

in my **composer.json** And. updated Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Next, When i am running my page, it gives following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\TodoApp\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Comment: You edited your autoload inclusion manually ?

Comment: sorry ..i didn't get you.. actually i am newbie in laravel

Comment: previously i have made another app in laravel in same procedure..there were no error at that time

Comment: Have you edited manually the file `bootstrap/autoload.php` ? If so make sure your autoload points properly Also, try doing clean, dump-autoload

Comment: no.i haven't edited that file

Comment: Have you done the way as i suggested in my answer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97374/discussion-between-itz-raghu-and-sulthan-allaudeen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you shall follow this way to include your html helper

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1"
}
```

and do

```
composer update
```

then change inside your `config/app.php`

I recommend you to follow [this](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) according to your laravel version

**Note :**

Don't edit your autoload [like this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fatal-error-class-illuminatefoundationapplication-not-found-in-pathtoprojectbootstrapappphp-on-line-14?page=1)

Comment: my laravel viersion is 5.1

Comment: Can you do this, remove the laravel collective under the require array , then do composer update

Comment: After that you shall include the laravelcollective from the composer directly instead of editing in the composer.json

Comment: Okay, now is your laravelcollective removed ?

Comment: thnks..it is running well..but i want to use Html collective

Comment: Yes you can do it. You ok with this ?

Comment: yes.. working well. :) after running composer require laravelcollective/html

Comment: That's great :) You shall ask if you face such any issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your composer file is probably messed up.

Run `composer update --no-scripts`

Answer (score -2):

```
   php artisan clear-compiled
    composer dump-autoload
```