# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in laravel

Tags: laravel

i dont really understand what happen to my laravel application. i never touch it for 7-14days because i need to focus on my project (written in CI). when my project was done, i go back to my laravel application to explore more about it. what happen next is beyond my imagination. i got this error on my browser :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\leadershipradar\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\leadershipradar\public\index.php(23): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\leadershipradar\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

i search how to fix it. and i found this on stackoverflow :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172644/getting-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found-in-laravel-5#

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172644/getting-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found-in-laravel-5
```

i follow all instructions and got nothing.
i also install new laravel and copy all logic, model, routes and view.
but the error still happening.

i did change the composer.json file into this :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1",
    "illuminate/routing": "5.1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.10",
    "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
},
```

when i run composer update, i got new error in my cmd.
[image]

please do help me to fix this issue.
many thanks in advance.

ps :

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravelcollective/html":"^5.2",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Why did you pull in 'illuminate/routing'? Any particular purpose?

Comment: Can you show your app.php?

Answer (score 0):

your composer require block is giving you the troubles

since your using laravel 5.2, 
you should use

`"laravelcollective/html":"^5.2"` 
and remove `"illuminate/html": "^5.0"` taylor no longer maintain this package 
 and also remove `"illuminate/routing": "5.1.1"` laravel/framwork already have compatible illuminate/routing pacakge required

Comment: i follow all the instructions that you gave. but the same error still comes up.

Comment: @gutasaputra then do you still received the error 'Your requirement could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.' ?

Comment: when i type composer update in my cmd, i dont received that error. but when i go to my laravel/public, i still get the same shit bro. idk why. its really confusing. i dont do anything. and suddenly boom, its corrupted.

Comment: then pls attach your composer.json file, which version of laravel your project is created on originally ? is it 5.1 ?

Comment: please do check my post. i did attach my composer.json file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the extension `mbstring` is required for installing the Laravel framework and might be disabled or not present in your system.

### On Windows

Open the php.ini file then uncomment the line with the `mbstring` extension (remove the ; from its beginning) then run the command (from the project root folder):

```
composer update
```

### On Ubuntu

Execute the following command to install the extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```